# Grouping rows to collapse/xxpand Highcharts Gantt resources

Tags: highcharts, series, group, highcharts-gantt

I need to make a mix between the 2 Gantt charts presented on the Highcharts site :
the Gantt Project Management and the Gantt Resource Management.
My need is to be able to group the different resources on the Gantt Resource Management to be able to collapse/expand the nodes as in the Gantt Project Management.

I tried to do this in a jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/qz2mLeo1/
I have the group to collapse/expand but one line per resource assignement (I expect only one line for the Jaguar and one line for the Peugeot).
When I try to add a Y axis category, I have one line by resource but I loose the group to collapse/expand... (demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/ekf3gzja/)

```
    yAxis: {
            type: "category",
      }

How to organize my series to get this feature ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hack because this property is preparing for axis type category, but when you add [yAxis.uniqueNames](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.uniqueNames) you can collapse the task and show these with the same name and different id as your requirement.

```
  yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true,
  },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/esq45bz6/